# $ a,b,c\in R ; a,b,c > 0, a+b+c=1$. Prove $ 1+3\sqrt {3}( a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}) ^{3/2}\geq \sqrt {3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

If $ a,b,c\in R ; a,b,c > 0, a+b+c=1$ prove that $ 1+3\sqrt {3}\left( a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right) ^{3/2}\geq \sqrt {3}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but for $ a=b=c= \dfrac {1}{3}$ I’ve obtained $2\geq \sqrt {3}$ which is true.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, my bad. Please edit and show your work to avoid getting your question closed.

Comment: Actually the original was $ \left( x+y+z\right) ^{3}\geq 3\sqrt {3}\left( xy+xz+yz\right) \sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}} , x,y,z\in \left( 0,\infty \right) $ and this is what I find after I noted $a=\dfrac {x}{x+y+z}$ and similar.

Comment: Brain123, Include this information in the question body. It's important to show the community your progress. You'll get more help this way.

Comment: Brain123, note that there must also be a mistake in your progress. In the proposed question we don't have equality when $a=b=c$, but in the inequality you mentioned in the question we do. If you show your work, we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: $2\left( x+y+z\right) ^{3}\geq 6\sqrt {3}\left( xy+yz+xz\right) \sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$
And, with the notation $ a=\dfrac {x}{s},b=\dfrac {y}{s},c=\dfrac {z}{s}$ and by $ m_{a}\leq m_{p} $ we get the inequities I’ve written

Comment: @Brain123 I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

The admissible points $(a,b,c)$ make up an equilateral triangle in the first octant. Which point of this triangle has minimal $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\,$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show $3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geqslant (a+b+c)^2$